# Will a MacBook from mid2010 run Portal 2 well?

Tags: portal-2, macos, graphics-card

My MacBook ran Portal just fine. It's a MacBook mid 2010 model with an nVidia 320M. Will it run Portal2 well?

Comment: My MacBook _Pro_ could run Portal _1_ averagely in its native resolution. I had the feeling anything lower than that and it would stutter. I wouldn't keep my hopes up for Portal 2.

Comment: Do you have the specs for your system? You can usually get them from the about menu. You'll need to know things like how much RAM and processor speed in addition to your video card graphics RAM as well (if it's shared or dedicated).

Comment: @Sorean - It's 256MB shared memory. I have 4GB of RAM.

Comment: 2.4 Ghz core 2 duo.

Comment: This is a non-Pro MacBook right?

Comment: @Thor yea, not the MBPro.

Comment: VTC in accordance with [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3411/can-i-ask-if-a-specific-game-will-run-on-a-specific-computer-system) meta.

Comment: Good good. This question should be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My brother played through Portal 2 on his Late 2008 aluminium 13" MacBook. The specs for that machine are almost exactly the same as yours, except that you have a GeForce 320M instead of the previous model 9400M. Judging by his experience, while you probably won't be able to crank the graphics up to the max, it should certainly be playable.

Answer (score 2):

According to the system requirements this is what you'll need:

```
OS: MAC OS X 10.6.7 or higher
Processor: Intel Core Duo Processor (2GHz or better)
Memory: 2GB
Hard Disk Space: At least 7.6 GB of Space
Video: ATI Radeon 2400 or higher / NVIDIA 8600M or higher / Intel HD Graphics 3000
```

Your system *might* be able to handle it, but the graphics will be your biggest cutback, and even then your game play might be slow and choppy (you didn't answer what your processor speed is).

Edit: With the processor speed you mentioned, you should be able to play it. But like I said, your graphics will take the biggest hit.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same MacBook as yours, I don't know why people are guessing that it won't be able to run Portal 2 properly.

I have played about 60% of the game, with all settings turned up to high, except FSAA (which is set to none). In fact on many of the levels, I can even play pretty smoothly with the anti aliasing turned on, at 4x.

I should mention that I have 8GB RAM. Rest everything is stock (2.4 GHz Core 2 Duo, nVidia 320M, stock 5400rpm hdd etc). Running OS X 10.6.7.

Answer (score 1):

I played Portal 2 on my Mac mini (2010), which is a Core 2 Duo 2.4 gHz and the same video card as you (GeForce 320m). Leaving the settings at their defaults (basically set to Low, with a few at medium), I was able to play the game with no issues. The early scenes don't look good graphically, but once you get into the test chambers you don't notice the graphics at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2009 MacBook, which has a NVIDIA GeForce 9400M (a step below the 320M, IIRC) with 256MB of shared memory. Yeah, you do have to min out the graphics options, but the game still looks pretty darn good and, more importantly, the framerate is smooth - *much* smoother than Civ V is even after I min that game's settings out, surprisingly. Whether my Mac is running Portal 2 "well" is relative, but it runs well enough for me - and the game as a whole is certainly fun enough - that I'm currently on my second play-through.